# Neo4J Unicity wonders : singleton or aggregation issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher, singleton

I'm new to Neo4J and have a question for you guys.
I import a CSV file and it duplicates my nodes instead of merging them.

**Example**

CSV FILE :

```
Id1,Id2,Relation
Alice,Bob,KNOWS
Morgane,Bob,KNOWS
Bob,James,KNOWS
```

I would like to have a result as such

```
Alice---(KNOWS)--->Bob<---(KNOWS)---Morgane
                      ^
                      |
                  (KNOWS)
                      |
                    James
```

Though what happens is :

```
Alice---(KNOWS)--->Bob
Morgane---(KNOWS)--->Bob
Bob---(KNOWS)--->James
```

I would like Bob to be a singleton, but it I get multiple "Bob" with different inner id's. I would like to merge all the Bobs together.
Anyone have an idea ?

*(Note that the arrow between James & Bob should be the otherway around on the "wanted result", but it's ok, it's not so much the problem here)*

edit : I tried creating a constraint before importing the data, but it doesn't seem to be working :
`CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:Person) ASSERT a.name IS UNIQUE;`

Thanks for your help !

Comment: what is your import query?

Comment: I use python in fact to load it up, it would be something like :
CREATE (a:Person {name:'Alice" + str(i) + "'})-[x:KNOWS {since:1999}]->(b:Person {name:'Bob'})

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your query to first MERGE your nodes and then MERGE the relationships:

```
MERGE (a:Person {name:'Alice'})
MERGE (b:Person {name:'Bob'})
MERGE (a)-[x:KNOWS {since:1999}]->(b)
```

Comment: So I solved it using a APOC library  and the following code : 
MATCH (n:Client)
WITH toLower(n.clientID) as name, collect(n) as nodes
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes) yield node
RETURN *

Comment: @theowl-Yte This answer shows how to *prevent* the issue. You should study the [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) documentation to understand how to change your queries to avoid data duplication.